# Show popout bubble above when no space available below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have build my custom drop down and it has a parent container who have fixed width and `overflow:hidden` in its css properties.
when the element is on the bottom of the div like :

[image]

I like to detect if the button is on bottom of the div then I change the drop down position to bottom currently its position is `position:absolute;top:30px;`

- my question is how to detect if the div is in the bottom of parent div

bootstrap dropdown works.
[image]

i have relative container and absolute dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a little more details regarding your dropdown and its container to get more precise answer.

If you had a 'relative' container with 'relative' dropdown you can find its position in container by:

```
var p = document.getElementById('dropdownEl');
var distFromTop = p.offsetTop;
var distFromLeft = p.offsetLeft;
```

and after compare that to your definition of 'being on bottom'

## Edit 1

That should work same for parent element being relative and child absolute.
Fiddle to illustrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/bw43wzqm/4/

Comment: i have relative container and absolute dropdown